# Problem configuring GPG pinentry

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, pgp, pinentry

I have two hosts, A and B. On A I have the `gpg` `pinentry` program setup to be `pinentry-curses` but I have no idea how I did it anymore. I can not seem to find the difference between A and B, but on A (which has no GUI) I can not get `gpg` to use `pinentry-curses`. On B it doesn't seem to matter whether I am at a terminal, a console, or have ssh'd to another host and back. I always get `pinentry-curses`. On A every operation fails due to inability to enter a pin.

I don't know what else to check. Here is everything I've tried looking at.

First, the `pinentry` symlink:

```
me@b ~ % ls -l $(dirname $(which pinentry)) | grep pinentry
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root            14 Dec  8 00:29 pinentry -> pinentry-gtk-2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         60832 Dec  8 00:29 pinentry-curses
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         48256 Dec  8 00:29 pinentry-emacs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         65088 Dec  8 00:29 pinentry-gnome3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         73792 Dec  8 00:29 pinentry-gtk-2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        103280 Dec  8 00:29 pinentry-qt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         52416 Dec  8 00:29 pinentry-tty

me@b ~ % diff <(ssh a 'ls $(dirname $(which pinentry)) | grep pinentry') <(ls $(dirname $(which pinentry)) | grep pinentry)
```

My `gpg.conf` files are the same (modulo comments and blank lines):

```
me@b ~ % diff <(ssh a "egrep -v '^#|^$' ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf") <(egrep -v '^#|^$' ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf)
```

The contents of my `~/.gnupg` folders appears to not differ in any significant way

```
me@b ~ % diff <(ssh a ls -R ~/.gnupg) <(ls -R ~/.gnupg)
2c2
< S.gpg-agent
---
> crls.d
8a9
> S.gpg-agent
9a11,13
> 
> /home/me/.gnupg/crls.d:
> DIR.txt
```

Neither have a `gpg-agent.conf` file:

```
me@b ~ % ls ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
ls: cannot access '/home/me/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf': No such file or directory
me@b ~ % ssh a ls ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
ls: cannot access '/home/me/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf': No such file or directory
```

Both have `pinentry-curses` installed:

```
me@b ~ % pacman -Ql pinentry | grep -i pinentry-curses
pinentry /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
me@b ~ % ssh a 'pacman -Ql pinentry | grep -i pinentry-curses'
pinentry /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

My environment appears to be roughly the same:

```
me@b ~ % env | egrep -i 'ssh|gpg|pgp|pinentry'
SSH_AGENT_PID=519
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yC9qsRh9Uf2c/agent.518
me@b ~ % ssh a "env | egrep -i 'ssh|gpg|pgp|pinentry'"
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.10 54816 22
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.10 54816 192.168.1.2 22
```

And the `gpg-agent`s on both hosts are invoked with the same args:

```
me@b ~ % cat /proc/$(pgrep gpg-agent)/cmdline
gpg-agent--homedir/home/me/.gnupg--use-standard-socket--daemon%
me@b ~ % ssh a 'cat /proc/$(pgrep gpg-agent)/cmdline'
gpg-agent--homedir/home/me/.gnupg--use-standard-socket--daemon%
```

Comment: Is `$DISPLAY` set in your sessions on either host?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt On A I only have SSH access and `$DISPLAY` is not set. On B (in a window) `$DISPLAY` is set and `pinentry-gtk` is used. On B (in a `tty`) `$DISPLAY` is not set and `pinentry-curses` is used.

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG uses a pluggable and configurable `pinentry` implementation, usually through symlinks on `/usr/bin/pinentry` or similar solutions.

On Debian and derivatives shipping the `update-alternative` system, you can display which one is setup running

```
update-alternatives --display pinentry
```

and change it through

```
update-alternatives --config pinentry
```

If you "messed up" manually, have a look where `pinentry` points to:

```
ln -l `which pinentry`
```

(you might have to recursively resolve symlinks, though).

Comment: That's not a GnuPG feature, it's a feature of the GnuPG packaging in Debian (and derivatives).

Comment: Both A and B are Arch. Symlinks where already posted in the question.

Comment: I remembered having read that up in the GnuPG manual at some time, but you're right. I'll leave it around but add a note on the restriction.